# different numbers of variable names and field specifiers error in tcl for linux server

Tags: linux, tcl

here i am using `set numCut [scan $inline1 "%d"]` in tcl script for linux server, but after execting script it's showing below error

```
`different numbers of variable names and field specifiers` variable $inline1
value is `2) "NYMEX UTBAPI Worker" (NYMEX UTBAPI Poller): STOPPED`
```

i searched in google for this then i got below

```
`
    0x1771b07c tcl_s_cmdmz_diff_num_var_field

    Text: Different numbers of variable names and field specifiers

    Severity: tcl_c_general_error

    Component: tcl / tcl_s_general

    Explanation: The scan command detected that the number of variable names
    provided differs from the number of field specifiers provided.

    Action: Verify that the number of variable names is the same as the number of
    field specifiers.
`
```

[here i got the above description](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/network/dce/library/publications/dceaix_22/a3u2l/A3U2L130.HTM).

Can anyone help me out how to solve this issue?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The ability to return the matched fields was added in Tcl 8.5. Prior to that, you had to supply a variable for each field that you had in the `scan`, and the result would be the number of fields matched (and it still is if you provide variable names).

Change:

```
set numCut [scan $inline1 "%d"]
```

to:

```
scan $inline1 "%d" numCut
```

Or switch to a more recent version of Tcl if you can, as 8.4 is almost out of its extended support period. (There will be a final patch release this summer to address some minor issues with build problems on recent systems, but that's it. We won't support it after that.)

Comment: So, as I should have noted, it looks like the server's `tclsh` is actually 8.4. You _might_ be able to use `tclsh8.5` instead to get a more recent version, or you might need to install (or have installed) a newer build.

Comment: i am using `tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.i686` in my Linux machine. when i am using like `scan $inline1 "%d" numCut` it's saying error as `can't read "numCut": no such variable` because here we are not using `set` to set the variable. please correct me if i am incorrect.

Comment: for `set numCut [string range $line 0 1]` it's not printing anything for input `2) "NYMEX UTBAPI Worker" (NYMEX UTBAPI Poller): STOPPED`
after putting `set numCut [string range $line 1 5]` it's printing `[0m2)`. can you please tell me what is issue here. i using this inside foreach loop. is foreach loop is creating any problem?

Comment: sorry guys making u in trouble. but i got the solution. actually first letter index is 4. now i m getting it as `set numCut [string range $line 4 4]`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Tcl error message is telling you that the number of specifiers in your format string `%d` is different to the number of variables in your Tcl command `scan $inline1 "%d"`.

So, you have one format specifier, and no variables and that's what the Tcl interpreter is telling you.

Try changing your command to `scan $inline1 "%d" numCut` and see if that works any better.